# Linking to DLL in C++ - same code works with Visual Studio, but not with MinGW

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mingw

I'm trying to use a third-party dll in a MinGW project; the dll came with a .lib and a .h file. Here is a boiled down example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


extern "C" {
    long __declspec(dllimport) _stdcall C843_Connect(long iBoardNumber);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "Attempting to connect..." << endl;
    long ID = C843_Connect(1);
    if (ID<0) {
        cout << "Connection failed!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Connection succesful! ID: " << ID << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The function declaration is taken straight from the header file. The code compiles normally with MinGW, but the resulting program crashes every time when calling `C843_Connect(long)`. However, the exact same code runs nicely when compiled with MS Visual Studio 2010. (I'm guessing the dll was built with Visual Studio, because it came with some VS sample projects.) Any ideas what might be going wrong and how I can get the dll to work with MinGW?

EDIT: I ran the program and a debugger, and the crash results from a call to a bad address. Here is the last four lines of disassembly, before the program crashes:

```
Address   Hex dump          Command
00401419  |.  E8 B2300300   CALL 004344D0
0040141E  |.  C70424 010000 MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],1
00401425  |.  A1 68724700   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[477268]
0040142A  |.  FFD0          CALL EAX
```

The first call goes to somewhere in msvcrt.dll, the second call crashes the program. Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: Describe exactly what happens when you experience a failure. It crashes gives no useful information.

Comment: Is `sizeof (long)` the same on both compilers?  IIRC that's one of the differences between 64-bit g++ and VC++.

Comment: Ever look at [MSVC and MingGW DLLs](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs)? (Especially the part about _stdcall functions).

Comment: Yes, I tried the procedure, but the end result is the same...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: On Windows 7, I get this box that says that my program has ceased working properly and that Windows is searching for a solution (which of course is never found...). It's the same thing you get e.g. when your program tries to mess with parts of the memory it's not supposed to.

Comment: @ben long is 32 bits on windows

Comment: @xqrp: Well, run inside the debugger...

Comment: What happens when you load the dll dynamically? dlopen/dlsym etc...

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, I guess it could work. However, I find that compile-time linking is somewhat easier and more elegant - at least when it works. Anyway, dynamic loading is my backup plan, in case everything else fails.

Comment: @BenVoigt: sizeof(long) returns 4 for both compilers, i.e. 32 bits (what one would expect).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are many [subtle differences](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm) in how the various compilers implement these so called *standard* calling conventions.

I had similar problems getting the Borland C++ compiler to call a Microsoft DLL even though the interface was defined as extern "c" using a standard calling convention.

In my case the code actually ran the entry point but it failed on return because the two compilers could not agree on how to handle the stack located return address.

Like, you my problems went away when the exact same code was re-compiled with the Microsoft c/c++ compiler.

**Edit:** This [page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/High-Level_Languages#STDCALL) has a low level description of stdcall which you could use to campare with the assembler that the MinGW compiler is producing.

Comment: This is nonsense. Stdcall is the calling convention of the windows api. If different compilers could not agree on what it is then the windows api would be unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Different compilers do different name mangling.  You need to compile all of a C++ project with a compatible compiler for it to link properly.

Comment: This is what `extern "C"` is designed for, there's no such problem with this code.

Comment: were this the case then the failure would occur at link time