# MinGw undefined symbol for C++ symbols in VC DLL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, mingw

I have a DLL that has been created using Microsofts Visual Studio. It exports functions and classes using

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

I am able to use this DLL successfully within another DLL that is build with VS.
However when I try to compile the same DLL with MinGW, I keep getting an "undefined reference" error to symbols from that DLL.
I try to compile it like so:

```
g++ -c App.cpp 
g++ -shared -o Live.dll App.o -lTest
```

Could somebody give me hint what I am missing? I  mean, this should be possible right?

I have tried various things that I found on the MinGW site, but could not figure out the issue yet.

Thanks,
Gerald

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9253606/560648 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116343/create-a-mingw-dll-to-be-used-with-a-vb-exe?rq=1 et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, this should be possible right?

Wrong!

Your DLLs are built with different toolchains, with different standard library implementations and who knows what else. They are incompatible.

**Build *all* components of your project with the same toolchain.**

Comment: So then the information regarding the interoperability of VC and MinGW libraries as explained here (http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls) is only applicable to C and not C++ libs?

Comment: @nutrina: There's nothing there about support for `thiscall`. Though it's not clear from your question what your calling convention actually is. A testcase would probably help.